# Creating a specifically formatted JSON file from a CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

Just want to start by apologizing if I'm approaching the JSON file creation all wrong, I've just been trying to piece together what I could. Please provide a better suggestion if you have one. Here's my issue:

I'm trying to create a JSON file from a CSV with 3 columns such as this:

```
000024F14CF24E42A5F36D7CB7A07C26,Name One,action-1
000024F14CF24E42A5F36D7CB7A07C26,Name One Variant,action-1
000042F8F69C4A048DDD4770DB7966C8,Name Two,action-2
```

The JSON format I need to accomplish is:

```
{
"topics": [
    {
        "id": "000024f14cf24e42a5f36d7cb7a07c26", 
        "label": [
            "Name One", 
            "Name One Variant"
        ]
        "meta": {
            "action": "action-1"
        }
    }
    {
        "id": "000042F8F69C4A048DDD4770DB7966C8", 
        "label": [
            "Name Two"
        ]
        "meta": {
            "action": "action-2"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

So basically I need to combine the names into a list keeping all variants if they have the same ID and I only need to keep one action since they will always be the same per ID.

The script I have so far which I will paste below gets close but I'm stuck. This script outputs JSON that looks like this where as you can see the actions are getting added to the label array. How can I separate the actions out?:

```
{
    "topics": [
        {
            "id": "000024f14cf24e42a5f36d7cb7a07c26", 
            "label": [
                "Name One", 
                "action-1", 
                "Name One Variant", 
                "action-1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Script:**

```
import csv
import json
from collections import defaultdict

def convert2json():
    # open the CSV file and loop through each row and append to the uniques list
    uniques = []
    with open('uploads/test.csv','rb') as data_file:
        reader = csv.reader(data_file)
        for row in reader:
            itemids = row[0]
            values = row[1]
            actions = row[2]
            uniques.append((itemids, values, actions))

    # using defaultdict create a list, then loop through uniques and append
    output = defaultdict(list)
    for itemid, value, action in uniques:
        output[itemid].append(value)
        output[itemid].append(action)


    # loop through the defaultdict list and append values to a dictionary
    # then add values with labels to the done list

    done = []
    for out in output.items():
        jsonout = {}
        ids = out[0]
        jsonout['id'] = ids.lower()
        vals = out[1]
        jsonout['label'] = vals
        done.append(jsonout)

    # create a dictionary and add the "done" list to it so it outputs
    # an object with a JSON array named 'topics'
    dones = {}
    dones['topics'] = done

    print json.dumps(dones, indent=4, encoding='latin1')                               

if __name__ == "__main__":
    convert2json()
```

Comment: Does your csv file have a first row with the column names?

Comment: nowhere in your code do you even try to build a `meta` section. you just slap everything into `out[1]`

Comment: @StefanPochmann No header row, but I can add one if it helps.

Comment: @MarcB You're right, but I am having trouble simply getting the action under the item instead of inside the label array. Was trying to solve that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're indeed close. I'd just build the structure right away. First time you see an itemid, prepare its entry and remember it, subsequent times just add the value to the label.

```
import csv

summary = {}
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as data_file:
    reader = csv.reader(data_file)
    for itemid, value, action in reader:
        if itemid not in summary:
            summary[itemid] = dict(id=itemid, label=[value], meta={'action': action})
        else:
            summary[itemid]['label'].append(value)

data = {"topics": list(summary.values())}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changed things a bit

```
def convert2json2():
    # open the CSV file and loop through each row and append to the uniques list
    # uniques = []

    topics = dict()

    # new_entry = dict(id)

    with open('uploads/test.csv','rb') as data_file:
        reader = csv.reader(data_file)

        #000024F14CF24E42A5F36D7CB7A07C26,Name One,action-1
        for row in reader:
            #can't use id thats a builtin function, but use all your other final 
            #json attribute names.
            id_ = row[0].lower()
            #you might have had the columns wrong before
            label = row[1]
            action = row[2]
            # uniques.append((itemids, values, actions))


            #skip the unique, a dictionary is already unique
            #populate it with a dictionary made out of your final desired json 
            #field names.  action is always same so populated on first pass
            #ditto id_
            topic = topics.setdefault(id_, dict(
                                                id=id_, 
                                                label=[],
                                                meta=dict(action=action)
                                                ) 
            )


            #after the first insert above, you have an empty label list
            #add to it on each pass...
            topic["label"].append(label)


    # create a dictionary and add the "done" list to it so it outputs
    # an object with a JSON array named 'topics'
    dones = {}

    #nope...
    #dones['topics'] = topics
    dones['topics'] = topics.values()

    print json.dumps(dones, indent=4, encoding='latin1')
```

and the output is

```
{
    "topics": [
        {
            "meta": {
                "action": "action-1"
            }, 
            "id": "000024f14cf24e42a5f36d7cb7a07c26", 
            "label": [
                "Name One", 
                "Name One Variant"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "meta": {
                "action": "action-2"
            }, 
            "id": "000042f8f69c4a048ddd4770db7966c8", 
            "label": [
                "Name Two"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is also so much simpler than where I was. Thank you for this!